# Is there a quick way to close a thread before the main code continues?

Tags: java, multithreading, join

I have a students working on a Simon Game for a final project at school and I have tried all day to solve her problem.
She is trying to create the game Simon. The program randomly selects a sequence of colours and highlights those colours by changing the colours of the 4 coloured buttons from the regular colour to white for a few seconds and then back.
Instead of highlighting one colour at a time white, the programming is making all colours appear white at the same time. So users don't know the sequence.

I have been looking up issues with running multiple threads and have tried using the .join() function. However, when that is used no colours turn white.

//highlights the colours that are currently in the array

```
public void play() {

   //loop through the array and look at all the colours so far     
   for(int i=0; i<round;i++){

             //red is the position in the array
             if(colours[i]==1){

                  Thread sleep=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                     @Override
                     public void run(){
                         //change the colour of the red button to white
                         redButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                         redButton.setOpaque(true);


                            //wait 
                            try {
                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                                }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            //change the colour back
                        redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
                         redButton.setOpaque(false);
                     }
                 });

                        sleep.start();


             }




             //yellow
             else if(colours[i]==2){
                 Thread sleep=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                     @Override
                     public void run(){
                         yellowButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                         yellowButton.setOpaque(true);


                            try {
                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                                }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                         yellowButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW); 
                        yellowButton.setOpaque(false);
                     }
                 });
                 sleep.start();




             }
             //green
             else if(colours[i]==3){
                 Thread sleep=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                     @Override
                     public void run(){
                         greenButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                         greenButton.setOpaque(true);


                            try {
                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                                }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                         greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
                        greenButton.setOpaque(false);


                     }
                 });
                 sleep.start();



             }
             //blue
             else if(colours[i]==4){
                 Thread sleep=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                     @Override
                     public void run(){
                         blueButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                         blueButton.setOpaque(true);


                            try {
                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                                }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                         blueButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN); 
                         blueButton.setOpaque(false);


                     }
                 });
                 sleep.start();




             }  

   }

}
```

Comment: Are those buttons, `JButtons` from Swing? I would not use threads at all in that case. I would use a `javax.swing.Timer` to schedule the different on-screen color changes.

Answer (score 0):

the code there basically says.

for all the steps in the sequence start a thread each.
then each of those threads (all started very soon after each other and not before the previous completes.) set the background to white for 1 second then back.

Usually you want to update the ui in the background so that you can continue to interact, but in this case you are playing a sequence and don't want any input. if updating in the background is required put the whole loop in a  thread and you will want to sleep between iterations of that loop.  otherwise just do it in the main thread.  once the sequence is done playing for the user it will pass control back to the event loop to wait for presses.

also the delay should be .3s < t < .5s 1 second is too long

Answer (score 0):

While you want to change the color of each button for 1 second, your main thread is too fast and finish within that second. Thats why it seems all lights change at same time.

Simple solution is to also to make the outer thread sleep for some time but that will not gurantee sequence of the threads. I would suggest to use `java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` to make the outer thread wait for inner thread to finish.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < round; i++) {
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        // red is the position in the array
        if (colours[i] == 1) {
            Thread sleep = new Thread(new Worker(redButton, Color.RED, countDownLatch))
            sleep.start();

        }

        // yellow
        else if (colours[i] == 2) {
            Thread sleep = new Thread(new Worker(yellowButton, Color.YELLOW, countDownLatch))
            sleep.start();

        }
        // green
        else if (colours[i] == 3) {
            Thread sleep = new Thread(new Worker(greenButton, Color.GREEN, countDownLatch))
            sleep.start();

        }
        // blue
        else if (colours[i] == 4) {
            Thread sleep = new Thread(new Worker(blueButton, Color.CYAN, countDownLatch))
            sleep.start();

        }
        countDownLatch.await();
    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {
    Button button;
    Color color;
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public Worker(Button button, Color color, CountDownLatch countDownLatch) {
        this.button = button;
        this.color = color;
        this.countDownLatch = countDownLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        button.setOpaque(true);

        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        button.setBackground(color);
        button.setOpaque(false);
        countDownLatch.countDown();

    }
}
```

As soon as the light changes color for 1 second you count down the latch using `countDownLatch.countDown()` you wait for count down to hit zero with  `countDownLatch.await()` in outer thread.